# Return a default value if exception is thrown

Tags: python

Is there a pythonic way of doing this?

I'm looking for a solution that is equivalent to the following:

```
import json

def to_json(some_string):
    try:
        return json.loads(some_string)
    except:
        return None
```

I assume there is a 1 line answer however I don't know what it is.

Comment: Nope, that's the Pythonic way to do it.

Comment: What made you think this was not the "right way" ?

Comment: You should narrow the scope of your `except` to `except ValueError` ([avoid bare except](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/doanddont.html#except)), but other than that, that's the way to go.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux - Python has so many neat tricks for simple checks like this. I assumed there is one for this as well.

Comment: Your example returns a default value if an exception *is* thrown, which is the opposite of what your question title says.  Which one did you mean?

Comment: @Shookie that is, in fact, the neat trick.

Comment: "*I want the following to work*" -- Does the displayed code, in fact, do what you want? If not, what do you **want** it to do?

Comment: @BrenBarn - You're right. My bad. Fixed it.